# URL Rewriting using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the URL like below; but not getting how should I do that.

**URL: www.example.com/?file_name=sample**

This is my URL I want to show it like:

**URL: www.example.com/sample**

that means I want to remove file_name parameter and get the parameter value and set it in URL.

Please help,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?file_name=$1  [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to add this somewhere appropriate in your .htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?file_name=$1  [L]
```

Comment: You should use `QSA` flag here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example on how to achieve this with `.htacess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # Not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # Not file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l # Not link
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?file_name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The rule is testing the URL with regex and will assign the first match to the `file_name=$1`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/?file_name=$1 [NC]
```

have a look at [htAccess Rewrite](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)